# Is it possible to use RF signal wires to let a model car center itself on it using phase differences?

Tags: rf, radio, transmitter, hall-effect, transceiver

I'm looking for a way to let a model car (1/24 to 1/18) know how centered it is on a road. I thought about using a buried wire in the middle of each lane of the road. Would it be possible to detect phase differences from one to the other side of the car to let it know if it is centered on the road? How accurate would it be?

I thought about using Hall effect sensors but eventually thought that it would be too prone to other magnetic fields.

Comment: `is it be possible?` has a `yes` answer almost always ... that makes it a somewhat useless question

Comment: I so the "robotic kids" to use color (black line) sensing.

Comment: @jsotola More in the sense of feasible / more practical that other approaches.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický Also thought about this but I would like it not to be dependent on the visuals of the road.

Comment: Possible, yes.  Practical, maybe.  You would need to use a pretty high frequency (GHz) for this, given the small distances involved.

Comment: Actual car systems use wire and magnets https://trains4africa.co.za/?p=3972